# How to output variables from the "RectTransform" component to the console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to output variables on screenshot from the "RectTransform" component to the console? For example I have an object with script "OutputScript". I tried to use

```
Debug.Log(GetComponent<RectTransform>().position)
```

and `localPosition` in the "OutputScript" but it shows the wrong numbers.

[image]

Comment: Is the screenshot what the output is supposed to say or what it is currently saying? You should provide both.

Comment: Exactly this variables I need to output in the Debug Log

Comment: The screenshot just shows a couple of values without context. What object are those values connected to? What game object is the script attached to? What is the code outputting right now? There's an awful lot of context to this question that you haven't provided, and without it, we can't really give you an answer.

Comment: All you've done is given a contextless name to your contextless script, and you didn't provide any of the details I asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().position
```

returns exactly the same value as

```
transform.position
```

since `RectTransform` inherits it from `Transform`.

**But** those are not the values shown in the `RectTransform` inspector!

It seems that you rather want [anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) or [anchoredPosition3D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition3D.html) which is the value you see in the `RectTransform` Inspector.